# dll hook function not called

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, hook

I trying to catch and retranslate keyboard and mouse events. So I use SetWindowsHookEx and function in dll. First time Ш have one big error - GetProcAddress can't get my function. That answer help me a lot [GetProcAddress returns NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044450/getprocaddress-returns-null)

Now i can call functions from dll and I can see effect from hook: my keyboard not work while programm is run. But hook not called.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinUser.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
HHOOK hhk;


int main(){
    HINSTANCE hinstLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("hookdll.dll")); 
    typedef void (*Install)();
    typedef void (*Uninstall)();
    typedef LRESULT (_stdcall *HookProcedure)(int, WPARAM , LPARAM );
    Install install = (Install) GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "install");
    Uninstall uninstall = (Uninstall) GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "uninstall");
    HookProcedure hookProc = (HookProcedure) GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "_hookProcedure@12");//omg
    cout << GetLastError()<< "\n";
    install();
    hhk = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, hookProc, hinstLib, NULL);
    cout << GetLastError()<< "\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        Sleep(200);
        cout << i << "\n";
    }
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhk);
    uninstall();
    return 0;
}
```

**hookdll.cpp**

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

HINSTANCE hinst;
HHOOK hhk;
std::ofstream myfile;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
LRESULT CALLBACK hookProcedure(int code, WPARAM w, LPARAM l)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCWSTR)L"HEY HEY", (LPCWSTR)L"Test", MB_OK);
    //never saw this message
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, code, w, l);
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void install() { 
    myfile.open("log.txt",std::ios_base::app);
    myfile << "\ninstall " << GetLastError();
}
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void uninstall() {
    myfile << "\nuninstall " << GetLastError();
    myfile.close();
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(  __in  HINSTANCE hinstDLL, __in  DWORD fdwReason, __in  LPVOID lpvReserved) {
    hinst = hinstDLL;
    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyboard hook allows you to intercept `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP` window messages. Console applications do not receive these messages unless there is an active windows message queue. If you want to see and process these messages in a console application create a window and give it keyboard focus. Make sure you do message `pumping` with the `GetMessage` and `DispatchMessage` WinAPI calls in the thread that owns the window.

If you do not want to create a window you can use `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` to intercept keyboard related messages sent to the active message queue of a thread. You will still need to use `GetMessage` to read from the queue or it will eventually start dropping messages.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Let me check if I understand the purpose of hooks. I think that my procedure is global and catch every events. If Im not right may be I need another function in winapi? I also trying use `SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL,..)` - result is similiar.

Comment: **Thank you!** 
To other who read this question: next question that i found by keywords http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7458807/why-must-setwindowshookex-be-used-with-a-windows-message-queue
It seems strange and I can't believe that process that call dll and link procedure and link to hook also should do infinite loop.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you are installing a global hook your DLL will get injected into any application that the hook can be applied to.